# Rails: Applying function to every record in table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a table in Rails and I would like to find all records of a table where a certain function returns true.

What is the best way to do this? I could of course iterate over all the records in the table and use conditional statements to test whether the function, given the individual record, returns true and add it to a list.

Is there any easier way of doing this something along the lines of Model.find(:all, :conditions => {...}) maybe?

Thanks

Comment: It all depends on the function, and wether that function can be replicated in SQL. If the answer is no, then you need to map over all relevant records to run your function.

Comment: If you can, provide that function so we can see if it's possible or not to replicate in SQL as Jesse said.

Answer (score 1):

```
Class MyModel < ActiveRecord
    def self.targetted
       find_each.select(&:predicate_method?)
    end

    def predicate_method?
        #something that returns either true or false
    end
end
```

this is a bit more Rails idiomatic :

- find_each will fetch your record by batches of 1000. it is better than all for your memory
- &:predicate_method : transforming a symbol into a Proc (with the # operator) will actually make your code call the method on each of the passed objects

Answer (score 0):

```
def record_that_returns_true_for_xfunction
  Model.all.select {|record| xfunction(record.some_column) == true}
end
```

This is seems like what you are looking for. This method will return an array of all the records where `xfunction(record.some_column) == true`.